# IOException and NullPointerException from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java

I'm writing a small program for an assignment and part of it involves reading from a file using ObjectInputStream. I've run into a brick wall because I keep getting errors when trying to close the file in the finally block as well as a NullPointerException but I cannot understand why. Any help is much appreciated! I have checked already and the file path is correct, so it is able to find the file.

Example file:
hello || apples, acai berry, bananas || shopping || 0.0005 || yes

```
 public Disease[] readInCancers() {
    Disease[] cancerList = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myData);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        while(true) {
            Disease disease = null;
            try {
                disease = (Disease)ois.readObject();
            } catch (EOFException eofx) {
                break;
            }
            if (cancerList == null || cancerList.length == 0) {
                    cancerList = new Disease[1];
                    cancerList[0] = disease;
                } else {
                    Disease[] newList = new Disease[cancerList.length + 1];
                    System.arraycopy(cancerList, 0, newList, 0, cancerList.length);
                    newList[cancerList.length] = disease;
                    cancerList = newList;
                }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfx) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be found");
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem with reading from file");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfx) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class could not be found");
    } catch (NullPointerException npx) {
        System.out.println("blah");
     } finally {
        try {
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem with closing file");
        }
    }
    return cancerList;
}
```

When I run the program, it gives a NullPointerException at ois.close() as well as an IOException that produces the pop-up "Problem with reading from file".

I have also tried changing how the file itself is structured, replaced the || (delimiters) with a word or even blank space but nothing changes.

Comment: Does the file you're reading just contain those strings, or does it contain actual Disease objects that you've written?

Comment: The file that is being read contains just those strings and I want to write it as an object.

Comment: That's your problem. You're trying to read Objects but the file contains Strings.

Answer (score 3):

Your `FileInputStream` is throwing an exception (I'm guessing from incorrect file permissions, but you'll have to look into this further); this occurs before you initialize your `ObjectInputStream`, so `ois` is still null when you reach your finally block which is resulting in a null pointer exception.  It's usually a good idea to precede `close` statements in final blocks by null pointer checks for this reason.

Comment: +1, but i think it's a better idea not to enter the try block until you know the resource is non-null.

Answer (score 1):

When using an `ObjectInputStream` the input data is required to be in a byte format that can be read into a serialized object, `Disease` in this case. If the format is not in the expected format a `StreamCorruptedException` will be thrown. If you are changing the text file manually, chances are that this exception is being thrown but the exact message is not displayed as you are displaying a generic *Problem with reading from file* message.

Displaying the stack trace will help

```
iox.printStackTrace();
```

Ensure that you are writing the objects correctly to file. Alternatively you could use a text based file, and use `Printwriter` to write, `Scanner` to read. You can use `||` for as a `Scanner` delimiter.